# VAST Error: on VASTClient.buildVastTree

Tags: javascript, xml, video.js, vast

I use VideoJS + [VAST/VPAID plugin](https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid). Getting this error on **any** VAST/VPAID XML when I try to play Ad:

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The video could
>   not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because
>   the format is not supported

I use [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin/565e0acd40aa4f9659ce222d33b2ded24a00bee9/spec/sample-vast.xml) and [this](http://ads.pictela.com/vpaid/46381?pretty=true&preview=true) as sample XML, and some of my own made.

Console output:

```
AD ERROR: VAST Error: on VASTClient.buildVastTree, error parsing xml z {message: "VAST Error: on VASTClient.buildVastTree, error parsing xml", code: 100}code: 100message: "VAST Error: on VASTClient.buildVastTree, error parsing xml"stack: (...)__proto__: Error
    at http://example.com/videojs/vpaid/videojs-vast-vpaid.min.js:2:29160
    at http://example.com/videojs/vpaid/videojs-vast-vpaid.min.js:3:6281name: "VAST Error"stack: (...)get stack: ()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: aK__proto__: ()<function scope>No Scopesset stack: ()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 1name: ""prototype: aN__proto__: ()<function scope>__proto__: DefineError.aTconstructor: Error()message: ""name: "Error"toString: toString()__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: get __proto__()set __proto__: set __proto__() undefined
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, never mind I've just fixed this by debeautifying all JS library files, possibly it's some kind of parsing errors.